# Include a leading zero in pagination

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I'm new to WordPress Development and have been teaching myself over the last few months how to develop a theme from scratch. Normally I can figure issues out on my own through forums, but I can't really find much on this one.

I've been trying to add leading zeros to my pagination if the number is less than 10.

I.e: < Newer   01 02 03 ... 10   Older >

Here is my pagination code. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
if ( !function_exists('palfrey_pagination') ) {
function palfrey_pagination( $range = 5 ) {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    // $paged - number of the current page
    global $paged, $wp_query;

    // Stop execution if there's only 1 page.
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;
 
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    if ( !$max_page )
        $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    if ( $max_page > 1 )
            if ( !$paged ) $paged = 1;
 
    // Add current page to the array.
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;
 
    // Add the pages around the current page to the array.
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }
 
    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }
    
    // The pagination
    echo "\n" . '<div class="content-block-common-large">
                    <div class="block-wrap">
                        <div class="inline-group flex-group relative align-center column-align-bottom">
                            <div class="column responsive width-450">
                                <ul class="pagination display-block relative align-center width-1of1">' . "\n";
 
    // Link to 'Newer' posts.
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) {
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link( '<div class="display-inline-block relative float-left"><span class="pagination-prev">Newer</span></div>' ) );
    }else{
    echo '<li><div class="display-inline-block relative float-left pointer-events-none" style="opacity: .6;"><span class="pagination-prev">Newer</span></div></li>';
    }
    
    // Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary.
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';
 
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );
 
        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }
 
    // Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary.
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link) ), $link );
    }
 
    // Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary.
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";
 
        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max) ), $max );
    }
 
    // Link to 'Older' posts.
    if ( get_next_posts_link() ) {
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link( '<div class="display-inline-block relative float-right"><span class="pagination-next">Older</span></div>' ) );
    }else{
    echo '<li><div class="display-inline-block relative float-right pointer-events-none" style="opacity: .6;"><span class="pagination-next">Older</span></div></li>';
    }
 
    echo "\n" . '           </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>' . "\n";
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your code gets to the point of outputing a number, adjust the number (`$pagenumber` in this code example) to include leading spaces with a variation on this

```
$pagenumber = 123;

echo sprintf("%'.09d\n", $pagenumber);
```

will output

```
000000123
```

See the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php , example 2, and other examples in there.